# How to customize mouse-over behavior of the url links in the PDF files?

Tags: hyperref, links

Does any one know if I provide an url in LaTex say `\href{url}{Frank}`
When I generate the actual pdf, if I put the mouse cursor over Frank but not click it, I want the description to be "*Find me on Linkedin*" rather than the url itself, how can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`cooltooltips` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) for this.  Here is a basic example essentially from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cooltooltips}

\begin{document}

Packages may be found on 
\cooltooltip{CTAN}{A link to CTAN}{http://www.ctan.org/}{Visit CTAN on
the web}{CTAN}.

\end{document}
```