# E-mail address for Anti-spam

Tags: urls, email

I want to prepare my CV. But when the mouse on e-mail, It will see ANTI-SPAM. On click e-mail then It works `\href{mailto:name@name.com}{e-mail}`. Is it possible?

[image]

[image]

related web site : http://www.tlhiv.org/

Comment: If it is CV for applying for a job, don't you think the recipient it going to get a bit annoyed? Plus it til probably only work in certain pdf viewers

Comment: check out `cooltooltips` package as explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148148/100482

Comment: `mailto` links are a bad idea. http://www.problogger.net/archives/2008/12/06/10-reasons-to-avoid-mailto-links/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example using code @Andrew Swann provided in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148148/100482)

Using the package `cooltooltips`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cooltooltips}

\begin{document}

%Provides mouse over and comment in PDF-viewer if supported    
\cooltooltip{ANTI-SPAM}{Anti-Spam Message}{mailto:<user>@<domain>.<tl>}{SPAM! SPAM! SPAM!}{Please no spam!}.
\end{document}
```

---

Testing the PDF has been done in SumatraPDF, PDF-XChange Editor and embedded PDF viewer. PDF was created on a Win7 machine, using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio.

### First results

SumatraPDF does not seem to support the mouse over or comment tooltip, as it only showed the mail address.

PDF-XChange does show tooltip and comment, but asks to save changes to the document.

Interesting side effect experienced while testing with PDF-XChange:
While the mouse cursor hovers over the link and the tooltip is shown, I couldn't use 
 <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch between windows.

This effect may be localized to my machine, but I think it could be seen elsewhere as well.

### Conclusion

The PDF-Viewer has to provide the feature, else it's no use.